# MySQL Upgrade on Windows and now SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed error

Tags: mysql, upgrade, ssl

I am in the process of upgrading my databases from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.

One of them is running on windows.  Replication was previously set up as:

```
change master to
. . .
master_ssl_ca="c:/mysql/ssl/ca.pem",
master_ssl_cert="c:/mysql/ssl/ccert.pem",
master_ssl_key="c:/mysql/ssl/ckey.pem"
```

This was all working perfectly fine with MySQL 5.7.

I then upgraded it to MySQL 8.0.36. This was fine until I tried to start replication, when I got an error about `unable to get certificate`.

I spotted that the syntax has now changed so that `ca` is now split into `ca` and `capath` so I changed that. But I still got the same error.
I tried changing the cert and key lines to just have the filename, as that's what the new fields suggest.

But now I get:

`SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed, Error_code: MY-002026`

Searching the web generally suggests permission errors on Linux. But this is Windows, and they were accessible fine before the upgrade.

Can anyone shed some light on what this error actually means, and maybe how to fix it. As I have several more to do and am relucatant to upgrade them until I know I can get replication working.

(n.b. removing all SSL options and setting it to ssl=0 works, but is far from ideal).